# Access variables from Variable Groups inside Python script task in Azure DevOps Yaml pipeline

Tags: environment-variables, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-pipelines, azure-pipeline-python-script-task

I'm using a Python script task of type 'file' in my Azure DevOps Yaml pipeline. I need to use the variables that I defined in my Variable Group in the Python file.
The following is my task on Azure devops yaml pipeline.

```
  - task: PythonScript@0
    displayName: 'Run a Python script'
    inputs:
      scriptPath: 'pythonTest.py'
```

Any advise on how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the variables to the script, using arguments, and you of course need to reference the variable group:

```
variables:
- group: variableGroup

steps:
  - task: PythonScript@0
    displayName: 'Run a Python script'
    inputs:
      scriptPath: 'pythonTest.py'
      arguments: --variableInScript $(variableInVariableGroup)
```

And then use 'argparse' in the script.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python?view=azure-devops#run-python-scripts

If you were using an inline script you could have done it like this:

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      print('variableInVariableGroup: $(variableInVariableGroup)')
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the Azure DevOps [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables):

> System and user-defined variables also get injected as environment
> variables for your platform. When variables are turned into
> environment variables, variable names become uppercase, and periods
> turn into underscores. For example, the variable name any.variable
> becomes the variable name $ANY_VARIABLE.

So you just have to access the corresponding environment variable from your script. In Python, this can be done using the [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) dictionary:

```
import os

my_var = os.environ["MY_VAR"]
```