# How to set variables, defined in Azure variable group, as env variables in Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, variables, environment-variables

We run integration tests, written in Python, in Azure pipeline.
The run is triggered in this way:

```
  - script: |

      pdm run pytest \
        --variables "$VARIABLE_FILE" \
        --napoleon-docstrings \
        --doctest-modules \
        --color=yes \
        --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml \
        integration
    env:
        <different_environment_variables>
```

Some integration tests will make connection to a database, and the properties, needed for connection to the database, are stored in a variable group in Azure. I can get them via :

```
  - powershell: |
      az pipelines variable-group variable list --group-id <some_group_id> --output table
```

but i do not know how to set them later as environment variables and use them in the python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the variables from your variable group directly in your python YAML pipeline like below :-

[image]

```yaml
# Python package

# Create and test a Python package on multiple Python versions.

# Add steps that analyze code, save the dist with the build record, publish to a PyPI-compatible index, and more:

# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python

  

trigger:

- master

  

pool:

vmImage: ubuntu-latest

strategy:

matrix:

Python27:

python.version: '2.7'

Python35:

python.version: '3.5'

Python36:

python.version: '3.6'

Python37:

python.version: '3.7'

  
  

variables:

- group: SharedVariables

  

steps:

- task: UsePythonVersion@0

inputs:

versionSpec: '$(python.version)'

displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

  

- script: |

echo $(databaseservername)

  

- script: |

python -m pip install --upgrade pip

pip install -r requirements.txt

displayName: 'Install dependencies'

  

- script: |

pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines

pytest

displayName: 'pytest'
```

```yaml
variables:

- group: SharedVariables

- script: |

echo $(databaseservername)
```

Pipeline ran successfully like below :-

Authorize and allow the permission to run the pipeline like below :-
[image]

Permit access :-

[image]

Pipeline ran successfully with the variable:-

[image]

You can also pass the variables in the pipeline with arguments and inline script with python task like below :-

```yaml
variables:
- group: variableGroup

steps:
  - task: PythonScript@0
    displayName: 'Run a Python script'
    inputs:
      scriptPath: 'Test.py'
      arguments: --variableInScript $(variableInVariableGroup)
```

Inline Python task:-

```yaml
variables:

- group: SharedVariables

  

steps:

- task: UsePythonVersion@0

inputs:

versionSpec: '$(python.version)'

displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

  

- script: |

echo $(databaseservername)

- task: PythonScript@0

inputs:

scriptSource: 'inline'

script: 'print(''databaseservername: $(databaseservername))'')'
```

Output :-

databaseservername variable was encrypted like below after running as an argument in the python inline script.

[image]

You can link the variable group in the release pipeline like below and call it in multiple pipelines across different stages too :-

[image]

[image]

Similarly, you can add Azure CLI task for your shell script to callaz pipelines variable-group variable list in your yaml pipeline and reference it like below :-

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2

inputs:

azureSubscription: '<Subscription-name>(sub-id)'

scriptType: 'bash'

scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'

inlineScript: |

az pipelines variable-group variable list

--org ''https://dev.azure.com/org/''

--project project --group-id id

--only-show-errors --output json
```

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Access variables from Variable Groups inside Python script task in Azure DevOps Yaml pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66204282/access-variables-from-variable-groups-inside-python-script-task-in-azure-devops) By Bo Soborg Perterson

[Pass Variable Group as Dictionary To Python Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69179255/pass-variable-group-as-dictionary-to-python-script) By Joy wang